# Setting up a has_many_through with separate database migrations rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, associations, has-many-through

So I have the following functionality where I have courses, course modules and course exercises.

I have it where users can mark off modules once completed when all modules are completed the course gets set to complete.

However, this is applying to all users, not individual users. So, for example, what is currently happening is that one user completes the course and when it's being marked as complete but if I sign in as a second user (who hasn't completed the course) it's being marked as complete.

From my research, I believe I could achieve this using a `has_many_through` association, but I'm unsure how to set this up.

Here is how I have things set up so far.

schema.rb

```
create_table "course_exercises", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "title"
    t.text "description"
    t.string "video"
    t.integer "course_module_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string "slug"
    t.index ["course_module_id"], name: "index_course_exercises_on_course_module_id"
    t.index ["slug"], name: "index_course_exercises_on_slug", unique: true
  end

  create_table "course_modules", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "title"
    t.integer "course_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string "slug"
    t.boolean "complete", default: false, null: false
    t.index ["course_id"], name: "index_course_modules_on_course_id"
    t.index ["slug"], name: "index_course_modules_on_slug", unique: true
  end

  create_table "courses", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "title"
    t.text "summary"
    t.text "description"
    t.string "trailer"
    t.integer "price"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string "slug"
    t.boolean "complete", default: false, null: false
    t.index ["slug"], name: "index_courses_on_slug", unique: true
  end
```

user.rb

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :confirmable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  has_one_attached :avatar

  has_many :courses

  def after_confirmation
    welcome_email
    super
  end

  protected

  def welcome_email
    UserMailer.welcome_email(self).deliver
  end
end
```

course.rb

```
class Course < ApplicationRecord
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :title, use: :slugged

  has_many :users
  has_many :course_modules

  validates :title, :summary, :description, :trailer, :price, presence: true

  def complete!
    update_attribute(:complete, true)
  end
end
```

course_module.rb

```
class CourseModule < ApplicationRecord
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :title, use: :slugged

  belongs_to :course
  has_many :course_exercises

  validates :title, :course_id, presence: true

  scope :completed, -> { where(complete: true) }
  after_save :update_course, if: :complete?

  private

  def update_course
    course.complete! if course.course_modules.all?(&:complete?)
  end
end
```

Completed modules

[image]

Completed course

[image]

Databases:

Course

[image: database]

Course Modules

[image: database]

But as I mentioned above, it's getting assigned to all users, not individual users.

Any help here is appreciated.

Comment: One option could be having the join table `user_course_modules` with additional column `status`. So `User` `has_many :course_modules, through: user_course_modules`

Comment: @iGian So create a new column in the course_modules table and just index the column with the user id?

Comment: Doesn't sounds good to me. I think a join table between `User` and `CourseModule` is better. You can then apply the same logic to `CourseExercise`. Anyway, better you try yourself some simulations. Also, check this doc: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association

Comment: @iGian So a new table and just say the associations in the migration? This is my first time doing this so I want to make sure that I have an idea of what I'm doing?

Comment: Just a new table (`user_id`, `course_module_id`, `status` or whatever) and few lines of code for the associations. For status you could use an enum. Let me know..

Answer (score 0):

As per the description it seems like you will be needing another table to 
capture the data user wise to show completed modules.

But another catch here is that you will also be needing to capture the progress
of course_exersises a particular user has completed so that after completing
all the exercises you can update the course_module.

Note: Entery in below mentioned table in done only when a user has completed the 
given exercise, also we will be having the timestamp as provided by rails.

User

```
has_many :courses, through: :user_courses
has_many :exercises, through: :user_course_exercise
```

UserCourseExercise

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :course_exercise
#table columns
user_id
exercise_id
```

Entry in this table will be done if all the exercises of a particular course has
been completed.

UserCourse

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :course_exercise
#table columns
user_id 
course_id
```

The approach of having two tables would be that when you need to show the exercise
data corresponing to a particular user then you will be using user_course_exercise
and when completed courses are needed then usign the user_course table